# Change Label Text at a Time Interval based on Character Count of a String within String Array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to have a character count of a String element in an Array (buttonTappedOutput) determine the time before updating a UILabel (outputText.text). Immediately after the label is updated, I'd like the timer to start again based on the next String in the array, updating again and again for all String elements (in order from element 0 to X).

**Why it's not working:**

Right now, my for/in loop is doing it's thing, the timer is overwritten for each loop, and finally, the final set timer (based on length of the last String in the array) invokes updateOutputText and updates the output text to the last String in the array. I've also tried calling my updateOutputText function within the for/in loop and including a delay in my updateOutputText function, but have the same result. I basically need to "pause" the execution of the for/in after each loop until updateOutputText does it's thing, but is that really the best way to attack this issue? A pause?

Also, am I passing the local variable 'output' the right way (currentOutput = output)? Is there another/better way to access it outside of the for/in?

**Here's my setup with the NSTimer:**

```
 @IBAction func eastPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    for output in trigger.currentDecisionPoint.buttonTappedOutput {
        currentOutput = output
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(output.characters.count / 5), target: self, selector: "updateOutputText", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }   
}

func updateOutputText() {
    outputText.text = currentOutput
    return
}
```

**With a delay in the updateOutputText function:**

```
    @IBAction func eastPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    for output in trigger.currentDecisionPoint.buttonTappedOutput {
        currentOutput = output
        updateOutputText()
        //timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(output.characters.count), target: self, selector: "updateOutputText", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

}

func updateOutputText() {

    delay(Double(currentOutput.characters.count)) { () -> () in
        self.outputText.text = currentOutput
    }
    return
}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach it is something like that (didn't test it though):

```
var index = 0
@IBAction func eastPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
     firstOutput = trigger.currentDecisionPoint.buttonTappedOutput[index]  
     timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(firstOutput.count / 5), target: self, selector: "updateOutputText", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)        
}

func updateOutputText() {
    outputText.text = trigger.currentDecisionPoint.buttonTappedOutput[index]
    if index < trigger.currentDecisionPoint.buttonTappedOutput.count - 1 {
         nextOutput = trigger.currentDecisionPoint.buttonTappedOutput[index + 1]  
         timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(nextOutput.count / 5), target: self, selector: "updateOutputText", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
         index++
    } else {
         index = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much! Just in case someone comes along wondering what this routine could be used for, I'm using this to simulate the time it takes for someone (game character) to type a String for a text based adventure. I think I'm going to make the time interval (3 + nextOutput.count/15) to give adequate time to read the current string...or maybe a time interval based on the current and next...to give realism and adequate time to read the current String. Thanks again for a perfect solution!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) Thank you for giving explanations and happy coding!